# Wijgrid will not play with Angular and Breeze together

Tags: angularjs, breeze, wijgrid

Wijgrid will not work with breeze and angular. To save me repeating myself, please have a look at this post:

http://wijmo.com/topic/wijgrid-will-not-play-with-angular-and-breeze-together/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model, like most models, has circular references. We are not wijgrid experts (at all!) but we suspect that the wijgrid component - at least as you have it configured - is unprepared for objects with circular references.

Objects with circular references are not bad. In fact they are normal and expected in entity models. A customer has orders and each order has a property that returns its parent customer. If you don't

We suggest you consult the vendor on this topic.

If you are using the grid read-only, you can write a simple function to copy just the data you want to display from the queried entities into special purpose "ItemViewModel" objects; then load those into the grid. It's even easier to query with a Breeze projection because that returns raw data, not entities; just remember that Breeze isn't caching those non-entity results either.

The situation is more complicated if you want to edit the grid.

I want to reiterate that this is not a Breeze problem. It is a problem with the grid control.

Comment: Thanks Ward!This has now been answered by the guys at Wijmo... (see thread link above)